# Units in Itunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to research the difference between a 'unit' and a 'total' while tracking my sales in Itunes Connect. How do they differ from each other, what are they?

Answer (score 6):

### Total

Is how many apps you sold in that category (Free, Paid, iAP, Updates). Period. Nothing simpler.

### Units

Is the *difference* in how many apps you sold in the specified time period vs. the previous time period.

For example, if I have my time range set to one week, Total would display 1,567, the absolute number of apps I sold in that category for one week. Units, on the other hand, would display the number of apps I sold in the last seven days minus the number sold the previous week. So, if in the last 7 days I had sold 1,567 apps, and in the seven days before that I has sold 1,500 apps, Units would display +67.